# List navigation from url addresses

Tags: php, arrays, navigation

I want to create a navigation from url addresses so that they correctly nest into each other by url.

1. I have an array of URL addresses and their ids:

```php
array(
    [0] => array(
        [id] => 1,
        [url] => "/admin/pages"
        ),
    [1] => array(
        [id] => 2,
        [url] => "/admin/store"
        ),
    [2] => array(
        [id] => 3,
        [url] => "/admin/store/products"
        )
     )
```

2. And the result should look something like this so I can create `<ul></ul>` navigation:

```
[admin] => array(
     [pages] => 1,
     [store] => array(
            [products] => 3
        )
    )
```

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: We would like to see your proof of research and attempt to self-solve.  This looks like a "requirements dump".  Asking a question here is not meant to be a replacement for researching and "doing something yourself".

Comment: I tried this:
foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $exploded = explode('/', $row['url']);
            foreach ($exploded as $explode) {
                $sidebar[$explode] = $explode;
            }
        }

Comment: Ditto on previous comment. Try to echo or print your output and just go from there.

Comment: There is a fair amount of script building to do from your attempt.  Your sample data is very small and may not expose all of the scenarios that you want to cover.  Your plain English explanation of the logic requirement is a bit light on details.  Please write all relevant info into your question as an edit, then delete your comments.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a php script to match above requirement directly. But if there are more parts in url, please make the change as necessary.

```
$array = array(
    0 => array(
        'id' => 1,
        'url' => "/admin/pages"
    ),
    1 => array(
        'id' => 2,
        'url' => "/admin/store"
    ),
    2 => array(
        'id' => 3,
        'url' => "/admin/store/products"
    )
);

$out = [];    

foreach ($array as $key => $arr) {
    $parts = array_filter(explode("/", $arr['url']));     
    $first = array_shift($parts);   
    $last = array_pop($parts);
    if (count($parts) > 0 && isset($out[$first][end($parts)])) {
        $out[$first][end($parts)] = [$last => $arr['id']];
    } else {
        $out[$first][$last] = $arr['id'];
    }
}

var_dump($out);
```